# How to put DNN skins in a virtual directory during development

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning, dotnetnuke-7

We're developing DNN skins, and we want to develop then in a different folder than DNN is looking for them, so they can be developed outside the DNN codebase.

Development Folder:
C:\TFS\{product}\{branch}\source\Skins

Original DNN Folder, now a virtual directory in IIS:
C:\DNNEvoqContent\Portals\_default\Skins

In IIS, we've set the \Portals_default\Skins folder to be a virtual directory pointing at the development skins folder. However, DNN doesn't read the virtual directory and work its way to the new skins folder; it looks for the exact path on the hard drive, which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to get DNN to use virtual directories for skin files? Note: This is only in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would totally not recommend doing skins in that manner.... You should develop your modules and skins within DNN as separate web application projects.

Here is a tutorial on setting up the environment
http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1

If you need a good starting point for a project for a skin, check out my HammerFlex open source skin. Download the SOURCE package, install it, open up the SLN (you might have to replace the .DNN file from the ZIP after install)

https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerFlex

Comment: I wasn't clear about that. Each skin's its own solution and WAP. I think we figured out what to do. We'll just use Publish in VS2013 to send the skin files to the folder DNN's expecting to see the skin in.